# Web API - Architectural Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i have a design question regarding a Web API infrastructure solution.

I have the following use case scenario:

1. A Dynamic Web Form Generator which produces an XML Configuration File where i have all necessary information regarding DB, Connection, Table Name, Fields....
2. A Web based Client which includes/creates a Web Form out of the XML Configuration file as an extension
3. Generic .NET Web API HTTP Service Layer which handles the Interaction Client/Server with generic CRUD operations

My question:

- Which would be the best approach to build a generic Web API, taking in account that the structure from webform to webform (DB, fields, tables, types) can be different.....
- Is it possible to create the Model Class at runtime starting from the  XML configuration file created by the Configurator?
- Or in genereal how you would approach it?

Best regards,
Patric

Comment: Beware the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect . Are you trying to make an application, or are you trying to make a new programming language?

Comment: I am trying to make an application based on the requirements above, more specific my question was regarding to build a generic service layer using webapi .net.....

Comment: We're using a similar approach in our web app. Firstly, you can't have everything dynamic. Especially when it comes to DB. We have simple XML files that are pretty much reflecting HTML, parsing in the runtime into HTML and render the view accordingly before sending it to the client. It works well, but it's important to define some limits and not inventing own ASP.NET

Comment: Why do you want WebAPI to handle HTML form POSTs? Why do you want to use a model generated at runtime? Your code can't access such a model anyway (as it doesn't exist at compile time). Just use MVC with `Request.Form`... Anyway this is off-topic and way too broad for SO.

Comment: @IvanSivak How do you handle the DB CRUD Operations?

Comment: @CodeCaster My problem is not the dynamic generation of the HTML Forms based on the xml file configurations, i would like to understand which approach is more suitable for handling the webforms POST's in a generic form via a generic interface, taken in account that those HTML Forms can have diff. fields. Note that those HTML forms resides in an external web client....

Comment: I didn't mention anything about that. I asked why you want to use WebAPI to handle form posts. And "which approach is more suitable" is too broad / off-topic.

Comment: The idea is to create a generic interface which handles all the requests comming from the dynamically created HTML forms which resides in external clients. 
Requests like:
- CRUD operations
- And other custom method calls

One of my thoughts would to create a generic table on the db side with 2 fields:
- Key=Value
- arbitrary number of pairs Field=Value separated by a delimiter

Out of this generic table i can construct my model class and a small parser for displaying the results in a structured way....

Comment: @user12282 we have a list of actions and each element, such as button etc. have optional `action` parameter that invokes AJAX post. In other words - there are always all web methods on the back end and it's up to XML configuration which one of them will be called.

Comment: @IvanSivak thanks for the answer, from my point of view would be interesting to know on the backend side (server side) if you are using generic parameters, because i imagine that the created HTML form can have different number of fields and also different types.....how do you handle it on the backend side?

Comment: @user12282 The set of fields and their data types is always the same. I guess we could call it a "pool" of fields. We don't have different data types. I personally don't believe it would be wise as data types have big impact. I can't see many options here. Do you really need such a dynamic aplication?

Comment: Ok...now it is more clear....yes we would like to go for the dynamic solution, it is for a write back extension for the BI tool we are using where the customer can specifiy the number and the type of fields he would like to have and based on this input an .xml configuration is created for the creation of the HTML forms.....the point is on the backend side to create this generalized web api for handling the request launched by the client.....we will think about :)....anyway thanks for your time!